# Excel VBA Month function throwing type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my data in the A column:

```
2013-SEP-04 10:51:42
2013-OCT-23 08:58:35
2013-OCT-23 08:58:35
2013-SEP-23 08:58:35
2013-OCT-23 08:58:35
2013-OCT-23 08:58:35
2013-SEP-23 08:58:35
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub getMonthNumber()
'
' getMonthNumber()
'

'

    Dim rowsMonth As Long
    Dim todaysMonth As Integer
    Dim todaysMonthDate As Date
    Dim column As Range, cell As Range

    Set column = Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    inactiveStaffConnected = 0
    todaysMonth = Month(Date) - 1
    rowsMonth = 0

    For Each cell In column
        rowsMonth = Month(Mid(cell.Value, 10, 2) & Mid(cell.Value, 6, 3) & Mid(cell.Value, 1, 4))

    Next


End Sub
```

1) Why the mismatch? The Month function works fine in this setup when using it straight in excel rather than a VBA script.

2) Is there a better way to parse the text into a date? The date string is too out of format with what excel considers a date which is why i'm issuing multiple mids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Month()` function in VBA takes a date and just returns the numeric (integer) month (e.g. 1 if you pass it 1/5/2013 4:30 PM).  You are getting a type mismatch because you're trying to pass the month abbreviation, e.g. "SEP", to the Month() function when it's actually looking for an argument with a date type, not a string.

You can convert your values into a date using the `CDate()` function:

```
MsgBox CDate("2013-SEP-23 08:58:35")
```

displays "9/23/2013 8:58:35 AM"

Comment: Clear explanation, concise solution. I would use CDate as well, if the format of OP is consistent for all his works. `MsgBox Month(CDate("2013-SEP-23 08:58:35"))` returns 9, which is perfect enough to manipulate to fit OP's needs.

Comment: @roryap - Thanks, this works. I wasn't giving Month the entire string value, I was braking the value apart into day,month, and year using the MID functions. Anyways, your solution is much better, easier to read, just great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what is the cell format of column A.

if it is in general format means this will work

k = "2013-SEP-04 10:51:42"
l2 = Month(DateValue(Format(k, "YYYY-MMMM-dd")))

if not means contact me again with the format you have in the excel.